# Magento Image Field Admin Grid not Saving

Tags: image, magento, upload, module, save

I am having an issue here and i think it's basically just because i am missing a step. When i save the file the image does save to the directory specified. However, when i go to edit the form the image I uploaded isn't shown.

This is the first grid module i have built so i'm a bit unclear on how it works.

In Form.php my image field is as follows:

```
$fieldset->addField('something_else', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'something_else[something_else]',
            'label'     => 'Something Else',
            'title'     => 'Something Else',
            'required'  => false,
        ));
```

I have set enctype to be: 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'

My controller has this code in the save action after if ($postData = $this->getRequest()->getPost()):

```
if(isset($_FILES['something_else']))
                {
                    foreach($_FILES['something_else']['name'] as $imgname => $img)
                    {
                        if($_FILES['something_else']['name'][$imgname] != '' && isset($_FILES['something_else']['name'][$imgname]))
                        {
                            $imgArray = array(
                                'name' => $_FILES['something_else']['name'][$imgname],
                                'type' => $_FILES['something_else']['type'][$imgname],
                                'tmp_name' => $_FILES['something_else']['tmp_name'][$imgname],
                                'error' => $_FILES['something_else']['error'][$imgname],
                                'size' => $_FILES['something_else']['size'][$imgname]
                            );
                            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader($imgArray);
                            $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','png','gif'));
                            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(true);
                            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'somethingelse' . DS;

                            $name = str_replace(' ', '_', $_FILES['something_else']['name'][$imgname]);

                            $uploader->save($path, $name);

                            $bazData[$imgname] = 'somethingelse' . DS . $uploader->getCorrectFileName($name);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            unset($bazData[$imgname]);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Is there something further I am missing to send the data back to form.php to display when viewing the form ?

I hope this is enough info and thanks in advance.

Comment: Print the POST array to Check the image existance field before saving. either you are getting this field or not in post ??

Comment: a var_dump of image array returns array(5) { ["name"]=> string(17) "How-tostyle_2.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(26) "/private/var/tmp/phpZqvj12" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(304120) }

Answer (score 1):

Try this peace of code
In your form for image field use this code :

```
 $fieldset->addField('filename', 'file', array(
          'label'     => Mage::helper('test')->__('File'),
          'required'  => false,
          'name'      => 'filename',
      ));
```

while in save funciton in controller use this

```
if(isset($_FILES['filename']['name']) && $_FILES['filename']['name'] != '') { 
            try {   
                    /* Starting upload */   
                    $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('filename');

                    // Any extention would work
                    $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png'));
                    $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                    // Set the file upload mode 
                    // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                    // true -> get the file in the product like folders 
                    //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                    $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                    // We set media as the upload dir
                    $path = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA)."test/" ;
                    //echo $path, $_FILES['filename']['name'];exit;
                    $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['filename']['name'] );

                } catch (Exception $e) {

                }
          //  echo $path;exit;
                //this way the name is saved in DB

            $data['image_path'] = $path.$_FILES['filename']['name'];
        }
```

.Hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the field value in your form. Like:

```
$data = array('something_else' => 'image/url');
$fieldset->addField('something_else', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'something_else',
            'label'     => 'Something Else',
            'title'     => 'Something Else',
            'required'  => false,
        )); 
$form->setValues($data);
```

Or:

```
$fieldset->addField('something_else', 'image', array(
            'name'      => 'something_else',
            'label'     => 'Something Else',
            'title'     => 'Something Else',
            'required'  => false,
            'value'     => 'image/url',
        ));
```